# Macro basic multiplication calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take the value inside cell I-8 Multiplied by the value inside H-8 and have this new value X, replace the contents of cell I-8.

I am trying to do this with every row starting with 8. (I-9 * H-9  etc)

I am already removing cell's will qty 0 inside column I with the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng
Set SrchRng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("I:I")) 
Do
Set c = SrchRng.Find(0, LookIn:=xlValues)                
If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing your sheet it would be hard to speculate, would this be something you want inside your Do/While loop? Realistically a macro is kind of overkill for this when basic formulas would serve you just fine.

Comment: Basically I am trying to get the Value I enter into Cell I to be immediately multiplied by the Value in Cell H. Sorry if I'm going about this wrong.

Comment: This isn't at all what your question is asking - what cell are you entering data into - I8 or B8?

Comment: Sorry - entering data into I8 -  Then multiply that number by H8 and overwrite I8 with this new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a different event for this to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 7 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Target.Value * Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

---

I feel it needs to pointed out however, that simply entering =H8*I8 into B8 will do the same thing.

Comment: Basically I am trying to get the Value I enter into Cell I to be immediately multiplied by the Value in Cell H. Sorry if I'm going about this wrong.